# No puedo abrir un PDF creado con itext7 en Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, xamarin.android, itext

Hice una App en `Xamarin.Android` para probar `iText7` ya que siempre había usado `iTextSharp`.

El problema es que no puedo abrir el PDF que cree y no encuentro el motivo.
Este es el código que uso para crear el PDF:

```
private void PDFTest()
{
    var directory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/Prueba";
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory)){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
    var pdf = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "Prueba.pdf");

    if (File.Exists(pdf)){
        File.Delete(pdf);
    }

    var writer = new PdfWriter(pdf);
    var docPDF = new PdfDocument(writer);
    var documento = new Document(docPDF);
    documento.Add(new Paragraph("Hola mundo!"));
    documento.Close();

    Android.Net.Uri uri;
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(pdf);
    file.SetReadable(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ //Mayor o igual a Android 7
        uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(pdf);
    }else{
        uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
    }

    Intent verPDF = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    verPDF.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    verPDF.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    if (file.Exists()){
        StartActivity(verPDF);
    }
}
```

No tengo ninguna excepción, pero el mismo lector de PDF me da el mensaje: "No se pudo acceder al archivo. Compruebe la ubicación e intente de nuevo".
Intenté instalando una App de lector de PDF (Adobe reader), probé con un `ChooserIntent` y sucede lo mismo.

Sinceramente ya no sé que más hacer...

Comment: comprueba uses-permission android:name.... que necesitas, si tienes para crear archivos etc

Comment: En el Manifest marqué los de WriteExternalStorage y ReadExternalStorage, además en el OnCreate los solicito si la versión de Android es mayor o igual a 6.0 (estoy probando con un Moto G5S con Android 8.1)

Comment: prueba generando el pdf con ireport, y ha el pdf que crear seteas los parametros, mas que nada porque si lo creearas sera un pdf sin estilos,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se asigna el `Uri` hay que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(pdf);
file.SetReadable(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){ //Mayor o igual a Android 7
    string strUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString();
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(strUri); //Acá estaba el error
}else{
    uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
}
```

Si la versión de Android es mayor a 7, el `Uri` hay que "parsearlo", para eso toma un `string` y lo obtengo desde el `Java.IO.File` que definí anteriormente.
Lo probé con un Moto G5S con Android 8.1 y me funcionó sin problemas.